# Table broken when display data from ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html-table

When I display the data on the table, it causes the table to resize. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Not related to SQL Server.

Comment: Hi there.  Please post the code to your view

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the need, one way is to use css and `overflow: hidden;` and it can be perfectly seen on this page of Stack Overflow, where long lines of code do not break page but the [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible.

Example:

```
<tr>
<td>verylongtexthere</td>
<td>verylongtexthere</td>
</tr>

css:
td { width: 200px; overflow: hidden; }
table { width : 400px; table-layout: fixed; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j6cyv0wz/